# Google tv chrome reporting GMT

Tags: google-tv

I have a Sony NSZ-GS7 Google TV that I am writing an HTML app against.  However, I am running into a problem with the time zone being reported as GMT / UTC.  I wrote a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tommyodom/YAU2U/) that reproduces the issue.  Calling getTimezoneOffset is returning 0 even though the time zone is set correctly in the box settings.

```
var date, offset;
date = new Date();
offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

I am wondering if this is just a bug on the Sony or if it is core Google TV / Chrome?

My Sony is running GTV 3.2 and Chrome reports as version 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with Google TV platform currently being tracked - if you would like to file an issue at http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/ it will be updated when fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I was hoping it was specific to the Sony so we could just buy a different box but I guess not if it's a platform issue.

Comment: It is something we are actively working to fix but I have no date for when it will roll out.